# Bootstrap - Align grid col to vertical-align on the middle and to the left

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

i have a grid with a row and two columns, what i need is to put the span3 in the middle of the column.

This is the result that i have now: [image]

html

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row index">

    <div class="col-lg-2">
      <h3>Para receber:</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col col-lg-10">
      <div class="span3">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Hoje</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Na Semana</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">No Mês</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Somente Atrasados</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div><!-- /.row -->
<div/>
```

Comment: try removing the margin from h3, or add the same margin to the span3, use your browser's inspection tools to analyze the CSS of your elements

Comment: The <h3> is on the center but the span3 no.. the span3 is on top

Answer (score 0):

The solution i found was create a form with a form-group and put a label to the buttons.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">

      <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>Para Receber: </label>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Hoje</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Na Semana</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">No Mês</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Somente Atrasados</button>
        </div>

      </form>

    </div><!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
```